# Indice automático en php

Tags: php

soy nuevo en la parte de programación, bien me preguntaba si alguno pudiera orientarme sobre como realizar el siguiente indice automáticamente en php

```
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
.....
1.9
2.0
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, por favor agrega lo que has tratado o investigado, revisa por favor [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Esta buscando imprimir estos valores en pantalla tal cual tu lo has colocado con los puntos o solo lo abreviaste?

Comment: Solo lo abrevie, lo que deseo es un consecutivo que vaya de 1.0 en adelante y que cuando toque 1.9 cambie a 2.0 y 2.1, consecutivamente @JulioFlores

Comment: @OscarGarcia si puedes editar y agregar lo que tienes al momento sería genial y de paso aseguramos que tu pregunta no sea cerrada, checa [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con un ciclo for y la variable final la puedes ajustar para realizar la iteracion que tu requieras. Ademasn la funcion number_format se utiliza para concatenar 0 a los numeros enteros

```
<?php
  $inicio = 1.0;
  $final = 3.0;
  for ($i = $inicio; $i < $final; $i += 0.1) {
      echo number_format($i, 1, '.', '') . "<br>";
  }
?>
```